# What do atheists (atheistic philosophers) think about the Spirit of Law?

Tags: philosophy-of-law, atheism

I thought that spirit is something belongs to the god's nature or to God. How I should to understand  the existence of the Spirit of Law? Are the laws the documents, rules and instructions written on the paper or something more, something spiritual?

What words they use to change nouns like "Spirit"? Or what is the material "spirit" then?

Comment: Are you referring to Montesquieu's book [De l'esprit des lois](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Spirit_of_Law)?

Comment: yes, this book, you said that it is the principles of liberty and society structure. Is it the Spirit? Whose spirit?

Comment: It has nothing to do with "soul" and "gods"... see [VIII.2 and VIII.3 *De l’esprit d’égalité extrême*](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/De_l%E2%80%99esprit_des_lois_(%C3%A9d._Nourse)/Livre_8): "La démocratie a donc deux excès à éviter : l’ *esprit d’inégalité*, qui la mene à l’aristocratie, ou au gouvernement d’un seul ; et l’ *esprit d’égalité extrême*, qui la conduit au despotisme d’un seul". In "the spirit of inequality" and "the spirit of extreme equality" the word *spirit" is used to mean attitude, or similar.

Comment: The same way they think about the "spirit of time".  Laws are more than what's written on paper, but the more need not be literally spiritual. It is in the practices societies have in generating, interpreting and applying laws supported by content in people's heads. The "spirit", all material though it is.

Comment: if spirit is nothing "with" what is it, if it is nothing mean why it needs? At your point it comes out that esprit is an excess noun? But at the title it looks like the cause of laws. "the Attude of law" - it doesn't sound.

Comment: Compare with Blaise Pascal's [De l'Esprit géométrique et de l'Art de persuader (1658)](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_l%27Esprit_g%C3%A9om%C3%A9trique_et_de_l%27Art_de_persuader) translated with [On the geometrical spirit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blaise_Pascal). Pascal was a well-know mathematician, natural philosoper and believer.

Comment: Pascal wasn't an atheist, he has reasons to write this way. But i ask what how atheists look at this today? What words they use to change nouns like "Spirit"? What is a material spirit then?

Comment: Yes, i do, and i like to use metaphors. But the metaphor is an equivalent to something. What is equivalent to the "Spirit".  Equivalent "the word *spirit" is used to mean attitude, or similar" doesn't relevant to the Spirit of Law.

Comment: If the question is about the meaning "The spirit of the laws" in the Montesquieu title, that expression just means something like "essence", and has absolutely no religious or metaphysical connotation in this context. You could also translate it as "intention". There is an expression in French that opposes "spirit" and "letter" to oppose "intention" and "practical application". You could follow the "spirit of the law" but not "follow the law to the letter" or vice-versa.

Comment: the same as God/devil definition. If it is good - that God do, if bad - the devil did. What is the Spirit? Good intention?

Answer (score 5):

The spirit of the law has nothing to do with ghosts, specters, spirits and other supernatural beings and it's nothing that requires faith, but is usually more about intent, purpose, character, essence or core of a/the law.

It's also often contrasted with "the letter of the law":
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_and_spirit_of_the_law

One denotes what the law literally says the other what the intend was behind writing it that way. Idk classic example might be religious laws where idk you're not allowed to eat pork. When it was written that was probably a good idea because you'd have a good chance of contracting diseases from doing so. Fast forward a few thousand years and it's not longer all that dangerous.

Now the letter of the law still commands you not to eat it. The spirit of the law would however have been concerned with the safety not with eating pork and so the law would be null and void.

Which is also especially relevant when the semantic meaning of words change but people still try to adhere to the letter of the law despite that constituting a de facto change in what the law is accomplishing.

So it describes something "abstract", that is hard to grasp and put into words so "spirit" is kind of a apt description, but it's more like "bless you" (if you sneezed) or "oh my god" (as an exclamation of astonishment) that found it's way into language but doesn't really concern people not concerned with spirituality.

Comment: I don't think that all religion people a agree with your identify point that the spirit - it is a cause to violation the God's laws, and you still say "it describes something "abstract", that is hard to grasp and put into words" -that is not determinate what does the spirit mean at all. But following your logic your "unnamed abstract" is close to "the reason" . The Reason of Law?

Answer (score 0):

The word 'spirit' has many different meanings, and you seem to be confusing two of them.

When we talk about the 'spirit' of the law, we mean its intended purpose- what were the law-makers trying to achieve when they introduced the law? Very often you will find that laws are drafted with insufficient rigour or foresight, so that if they are interpreted literally (what we would call 'the letter of the law') they might contain 'loopholes' or appear to have unintended consequences which are incompatible with the intended purpose, or spirit, of the law.

Comment: Your "spirit" definition looks like the refers to something, or prerequisite. Trying to archive what? In logic Law definite in Spirit. You said that Spirit is trying to do (good?), but how it ll be they don't know, if it ll bad we tell it is not The Spirit it is the letter. Looks same as the devil did this.